# How to enable R in ExternalLanguage cell?

Tags: external-calls, rlink

Mathematica 12.1 adds support for R in the ExternalLanguage cell. But this does not work out of the box.

[image]

Mathematica downloads very old `RLinkRuntime-Windows-9.0.0.0` (R 2.14!).

[image]

How to enable R in the `ExternalLanguage` cell?

Comment: [Related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216594/installing-r-libraries-for-use-with-externalevaluate)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I did not see this question. Should I delete mine as a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think yours is exact dupe, because that one was concerned with using R packages, which is a slightly different topic. So I would definitely keep this one too.

Comment: Worked out of the box on Mathematica 12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020) (after automatically installing R).

Answer (score 6):

**On Windows:**

1. download and install R: https://cloud.r-project.org/
   The installation directory is `C:\R` in my case.
2. run R and evaluate: `install.packages('rJava')`
3. fix `C:\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Components\ExternalEvaluate_R\ExternalEvaluate\R.wl`: `InstallR["RHomeLocation"->"C:\\R","NativeLibLocation"->"C:\\R\\library\\rJava\\jri\\x64"]`
4. enjoy R in the `ExternalLanguage` cell:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1, that will certainly work, although this method is probably more intruding than one would like. We will make an effort to support the choice of R versions through `ExtrernalEvaluate` out of the box a.s.a.p.

Comment: Some more details on using RLink with modern versions of R were also discussed [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1807709)

Comment: What about RStudio?